# Convert a complicated string into an array in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a **php** variable that comes from a form that needs tidying up. I hope you can help.

The variable contains a list of items (possibly two or three word items with a space in between words).
I want to convert it to a comma separated list with no superfluous white space. I want the divisions to fall only at commas, semi-colons or new-lines. Blank cannot be an item.

Here's a comprehensive example (with a deliberately messy input):

```
Variable In: "dog, cat         ,car,tea pot,,  ,,, ;;(++NEW LINE++)fly,     cake"
Variable Out "dog,cat,car,tea pot,fly,cake"
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can start by **splitting the string** into "useful" parts, with **[`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split)**, and, then, **[`implode`](http://php.net/implode) those parts back together** :

```
$str_in = "dog, cat         ,car,tea pot,,  ,,, ;;
fly,     cake";

$parts = preg_split('/[,;\s]/', $str_in, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

$str_out = implode(',', $parts);

var_dump($parts, $str_out);
```

*(Here, the regex will split on '`,`', '`;`', and '`\s`', which means any whitespace character -- and we only keep non-empty parts)*

Will get you, for `$parts` :

```
array
  0 => string 'dog' (length=3)
  1 => string 'cat' (length=3)
  2 => string 'car' (length=3)
  3 => string 'tea' (length=3)
  4 => string 'pot' (length=3)
  5 => string 'fly' (length=3)
  6 => string 'cake' (length=4)
```

And, for `$str_out` :

```
string 'dog,cat,car,tea,pot,fly,cake' (length=28)
```

---

**Edit after the comment :** sorry, I didn't notice that one ^^

In that case, you can't split by white-space :-( I would probably split by '`,`' or '`;`', iterate over the parts, using **[`trim`](http://php.net/trim)** to remove white-characters at the beginning and end of each item, and only keep those that are not empty :

```
$useful_parts = array();
$parts = preg_split('/[,;]/', $str_in, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    $part = trim($part);
    if (!empty($part)) {
        $useful_parts[] = $part;
    }
}
var_dump($useful_parts);
```

Executing this portion of code gets me :

```
array
  0 => string 'dog' (length=3)
  1 => string 'cat' (length=3)
  2 => string 'car' (length=3)
  3 => string 'tea pot' (length=7)
  4 => string 'fly' (length=3)
  5 => string 'cake' (length=4)
```

And imploding all together, I get, this time :

```
string 'dog,cat,car,tea pot,fly,cake' (length=28)
```

Which is better ;-)

Comment: That's a great answer. How would you keep "tea pot" as one item on the final list?

Comment: @Patrick : I edited my answer with a second idea -- didn't quite notice that case ^^

Answer (score 1):

You could use `explode` and `trim` and `str_replace` to get the array, manually remove specific characters, and then turn it back into an array.

```
function getCleanerStringFromString($stringIn) {
    ///turn the string into an array with a comma as the delimiter
    $myarray = explode(",",$stringin);

    for ($ii =0; $ii < count($myarray); $ii++) {
        ///remove new lines, semi colons, etc
        ///use this line as many times as you'd like to take out characters
        $myarray($ii) = str_replace(";","",$myarray($ii);


        ////remove white spaces
        $myarray($ii) = trim($myarray($ii));

    }

    //then turn it back into an array:
    $backstring = implode(","$myarray);

    return $backstring;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Explode entire string on the comma, walk through that array, first matching all characters that are not a-zA-Z0-9 (and space), then trimming remaining leading/trailing spaces. If empty, unset the item from the array. Implode back to a string.

Ideally, this allows for more messy characters than just ,;\s\n etc.

```
$strIn = "dog, cat         ,car,tea pot,,  ,,, ;;(++NEW LINE++)fly,     cake";
$firstArray = explode(",", $strIn);

$searchPattern = "/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+/";

function removeViolators($item, $key) {
    preg_replace($searchPattern, "", $item);
    trim($item);
    if (empty($item)) {
        unset($item);
    }
}

array_walk($firstArray, removeViolators);
$strOut = implode(",", $firstArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Split then grep, seems to give the expected output:

```
$array = preg_split('/\s*[;,\n]\s*/', $string);
$array = preg_grep('/^\s*$/', $array, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
$string = implode(',', $array);
```

EDIT: actually grep isn't necessary:

```
$array = preg_split('/\s*[;,\n]\s*/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$string = implode(',', $array);
```